# Ubuntu 12.04 in login loop as lightdm-session says upstart not found

Tags: 12.04, login, lightdm, upstart

I tried to install a package `systemd` (this replaces `upstart` in Utopic 14.10 and up). See my yesterday question [How to Re Generate All Gnome Schemas for Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562555/how-to-re-generate-all-gnome-schemas-for-ubuntu-12-04). The result was that it didn't work. I removed all the packages (including dependencies) I installed and reverted back to stock Precise 12.04 packages. However, when starting Ubuntu I am stuck in a looping login screen, though my password is checked.

From what I learned yesterday, I typed `<Ctrl><Alt><F2>` to enter a login shell. then I looked at the `~/.xsession-errors` file:

```
$ cat .xsession-errors
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 5: exec: upstart: not found
```

I re-installed the `lightdm` and upstart `packages` to no avail. I found a description of [How a desktop user GUI session gets started with Ubuntu 12.04-14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150487/what-happens-under-the-covers-to-log-me-in-and-start-up-unity-or-another-graphic). My system fails in the lightdm-session part. However I don't know where. I seem to lack as well an `/etc/xprofile` `~/.xprofile` and an `~/.xsessionrc` mentioned in the above webpage. Are these files required and how I can get working ones ?

Basically it fails to open an X-Window session.

Can anyone tell me how to go back to the genuine Precise 12.04 logon ?

Comment: Interesting - the /usr/sbin/lightdm-session script on my 12.04 installation doesn't mention upstart anywhere, and in fact there's no executable called upstart as far as I can tell. Have you tried **purging** and then re-installing `lightdm`?

Comment: Yes I did $ sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends lightdm upstart ubuntu-system-service then $ sudo dpkg -i for these 3 packages ... To no avail. It looks like there is no solution to this situation. I have already lost 3 days. I already backed up my /home /etc and /var in addition my /usr/local/svn repos and /opt. And tomorrow I will go for upgrading to Trusty 14.04 although I am not happy at all that this system is the last from Ubuntu to stick with Upstart instead of Deamond ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `upstart-bin`. This is because the user session uses upstart, but you uninstalled upstart so it does not work correctly. With Upstart, user sessions can use upstart without Upstart running as the system init.